# How to get the ~/layout/default.vue applied to ~/error.vue in a Nuxt 3 (Vue 3) application?

Tags: typescript, error-handling, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, nuxtjs3

I am using Nuxt 3 and Vue 3. I have a directory structure for a default layout that I want applied to all pages including the `error.vue` page.

NOTE: The `error.vue` file is in the root of the project.

My directory structure is as follows:

```
project-application
  - /assets/
      - /styles/
          - errorStyles.scss
  - /components/
  - /composables/
  - /layouts/
      - default.vue
  - /pages/
      - index.vue
      - /course/
          - [id].vue
  - /public/
  - /server/
  - /utils/
  - /app.vue
  - /error.vue
  - /nuxt.config.ts
  - package.json
  - ...
```

Currently, the `default.vue` gets applied to everything in my `pages` folder.

QUESTION: How do I get my `default.vue` layout to be applied to my  `error.vue` (located in the project root folder) also.

`app.vue` file

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <NuxtLayout>
      <NuxtPage />
    </NuxtLayout>
  </div>
</template>
```

`error.vue` file

```js
<template>
  <div class="errorSection">
    <p>ERROR DETAILS: {{ error.statusCode }} {{ error.statusMessage }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
defineProps({
  error: {
    type: Object,
    default: null,
  },
});
</script>

<style setup="scss" scoped>
@import "./assets/styles/errorStyles.scss";
</style>
```

`default.vue` file

```js
<template>
  <div class="defaultLayout">
    <div class="imageContainer">
      <nuxt-img
        src="../public/logo.png"
        alt="Company logo"
      />
    </div>
    <slot />
  </div>
</template>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
... some styles here
</style>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All I had to do in my `error.vue` file was add the `NuxtLayout` and `default.vue` was applied to my error page as well.

`error.vue` file

```
<template>
  <NuxtLayout>
    <div class="errorSection">
      <p>ERROR DETAILS: {{ error.statusCode }} {{ error.statusMessage }}</p>
    </div>
  </NuxtLayout>
</template>
```

Comment: If you want to use another layout: `<NuxtLayout name="otherLayoutName">`. Explained [here](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/components/nuxt-layout)